# Oneway pairwise anova with summary data's (means, sd and sizes)?

Tags: distributions, anova

Quite new to distribution analysis, I'm puzzled what to do with the adjustments data's :

I have response times from a 3 conditions pairwise experiment. I have quite a hard time before succeeding an analysis of the distributions that lead me to choose an ex-Gaussian adjustment which fit quite well my distributions (using fitdistrplus package). Each adjustment gives me 3 parameters: mu and sigma for the Gaussian component and tau for the exponential component. Each one come with sd.
[image: see : ex-Gaussian adjustment for one of the 3 distributions]

I'm used conducting Anova with the entire sample, but here, how one can check for effects of the three conditions on the ex-gaussian adjustments (mu, sigma and tau).
For instance, I have for mu :

```
mu <- c(22.45, 18.17, 23.28) # mean fit for the Gaussian component
mu.sd <- c(2.06, 1.82, 2.18) # sd of mu
mu.n <- c(96, 96, 96)        # group sizes
```

I found one function to check for effect with summary data's :

```
library(rpsychi)
mu.ind.anova <- ind.oneway.second(mu,mu.sd,mu.n)
```

But this function is for independent design and I have a pairwise design, so how can I conduct an Anova knowing only the means, sd and groups size?
Or, how to check for effects when working with ex-Gaussian parameters adjustments?